# Excel - Return the first negative number of a column

Tags: excel, function

I'm using Excel 2010 and I'm looking for a way to return the first negative number of a column. For instance, I have the following numbers distributed in a column:
1
4
6
-3
4
-1
-10
8
Which function could I use to return -3?
Thanks!

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried so far.  Also include some code that you have to at least read the data.

Comment: See http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/597136-find-first-negative-number-in-a-list.html

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650306/excel-formula-to-determine-cell-id-when-a-series-of-numbers-turns-negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be interpreted two ways... If all the numbers are in a single cell (one column) as a string, the MID function can be used. If the numbers are in A1, a formula that could work is this:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1),SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH("-",A1))-SEARCH("-",A1)))
```

If the numbers are each in their own columns (in my example, A3:H3), a different technique must be used:

```
{=INDEX(A3:H3,1,MATCH(TRUE,A3:H3<0,0))}
```

Don't type the { } - enter the equation using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

In each case, the formula will return the number -3, which is the first negative number in the series.

Comment: Note that if all the numbers are in a single column, 1 number per row then this changes the functions, Ie the second becomes `{=INDEX(A3:H3,MATCH(TRUE,A3:H3<0,0),1)}` (swap column/row)

Comment: You don't really need to vary the formula - if you use this version: `=INDEX(range,MATCH(TRUE,range<0,0))` that will work whether range is a single column or single row

Comment: Excel Tatics, I tested what you've suggested and it worked perfectly! Thanks Excel Tatics, Barry Houdini and Java Devil for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, avoiding the array formula (which are a big source of performance issues):

```
=LOOKUP(1;1/(M2:M15<0);M2:M15)
```

(I assume your numbers are in the M2:M15 range).

This will return the first number matching the "<0" condition. You may use any other condition, including text comparisons.

You may also extract the value of another array corresponding to the matching cell:

```
=LOOKUP(1;1/(M2:M15<>"OK");T2:T15)
```

In this example, the first cell containing another string than "OK" will be searched for in the m2:m15 array and the corresponding value in array t2:t15 will be returned.

Please note that the usage of the lookup function should be avoided whenever possible (but in this case, it's very handy !)

(I got the original inspiration for this answer from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/398521/excel-get-cell-value-which-is-not-match-in-a-row))

Comment: the first formula didn't work for me in google sheets. Does this only work in Excel?
My exact usage: `=LOOKUP(1,1/(O16:O81<0),O16:O81)`