# Multiple Match Function Returns Error Against Table with One Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following multi-match array function fails against a table with only 1 row. However it works as as soon as there is another row added.

```
{=MATCH("A"&"C",myTable[Col1]&myTable[Col3],0)}
```

*curly brackets added to show* **array** *formula*

See picture as example

[image]

Is there anyway to force this to work for at times my real data may only have 1 row in the table? (And this also works with only one row of data not explicity formatted as a table).

This modification doesn't work either:

```
=MATCH("A"&"C",myTable[[#Data],[Col1]]&myTable[[#Data],[Col3]],0)
```

Comment: This answer seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29671342/6651557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modification works, for an alternative to @ScottCraner's answer.

```
{=MATCH("A"&"C",myTable[[#All],[Col1]]&myTable[[#All],[Col3]],0)-1}
```

*Curly brackets added to designate this needs to be entered as an array formula (by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`*

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why but, you can avoid it by using Aggregate:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table1[Col1])-MIN(ROW(Table1[Col1]))+1)/((Table1[Col1]="A")*(Table1[Col3]="C")),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. +1 for providing working solution. My only issue is readability at this point. See my update about the modification I found that does work (and seems a little less messy and understandable than `AGGREGATE`.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  I guess it is a matter of opinion.  The Aggregate, when using array formulas, is easier to understand than others.  As it has the conditions spelled out.

Comment: Fair point. I'll admit I am not 100% comfortable / experienced with it either, so that may skew my viewpoint. For instance, I don't really understand how this part `(ROW(Table1[Col1])-MIN(ROW(Table1[Col1]))+1)/((Table1[Col1]="A")*(Table1[Col3]="C"))` goes with the `SMALL` function.

Comment: If you have time and a little patience, can you shed some light to lead me in right direction?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman It is building an array of row numbers and `#DIV/0` errors.  The `(ROW(Table1[Col1])-MIN(ROW(Table1[Col1]))+1)` makes sure that the first row in the table is returning 1, if we were not using tables I would have only done the `ROW()` as I would use the full column in index so: `=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C6)/...` so I do not need to do the rest of the math. (continued)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the denominator is what causes the errors. Remember that when we do any math on a TRUE/FALSE it reverts to the BOOLEAN value of 1/0 respectively, so when either of the two are false the denominator is 0 and when we divide by 0 we get an error.  The second criterion of `6` in the aggregate ignores these errors and we get an array of row numbers that the conditions returned TRUE.  The `15` says we want the rank of the smallest denoted by the last criterion in the aggregate, in this case `1` which is the smallest. (Continued).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The k value can used to our advantage also, when we want a list of values that meet the requirement we do not need to do the countif() array formula to move to the next we simply use ROW(1:1) and as the formula is dragged down the next row that meets the criteria is passed to the index and the next value is returned.  All without the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Something to study up for sure. Appreciate the generosity in explanation :). On reading a 2nd time I think I get it more clearly. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, it seems you can just wrap your original formula in an iferror:

```
{=IFERROR(MATCH("A"&"C",myTable[Col1]&myTable[Col3],0),IF("A"&"C"=myTable[Col1]&myTable[Col3],1,0))}
```

This also gives you the opportunity to build in a return value in the case that you do not have a match in the table at all.