# MATCH function on Excel returns error

Tags: excel, match

For some reason the MATCH function on excel returns an error. 
Unfortunately I cannot share the data in order to replicate the problem but I was wondering if someone more experienced than I am could possibly find a small error in my code or something that I missed.

I used the functions according to these [directions](http://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/) and I also I tried a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668143/excel-index-match-failing-for-single-cell-range) but neither source helped much.

```
=INDEX(IB_RAW!A2:L301,MATCH(1,(IB_RAW!$B:$B=IB!P10)*(IB_RAW!$D:$D=IB!A9)*(IB_RAW!$C:$C=IB!Q9)*(IB_RAW!$L:$L=IB!P7),0),IB_RAW!$J:$J)
```

I will try to describe the data as best as I can:

- IB: The sheet where I want to show the extracted value
- IB_RAW: The sheet where I get the information from
- A2:L301: The whole dataset that I am using to look for the arguments
  (in IB_RAW)
- J: The value I want to extract (in IB_RAW)

The issue is with the `MATCH` function, as it returns `#N/A`, I've used the `Show Calculation Steps...` option to see where the problem is,

So for

```
(IB_RAW!$B:$B=IB!P10) returns TRUE
(IB_RAW!$D:$D=IB!A9) returns FALSE
(IB_RAW!$C:$C=IB!Q9) returns TRUE
(IB_RAW!$L:$L=IB!P7) returns TRUE
```

Therefore `MATCH(1,0,0)` but this returns `#N/A` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The solution was from this [detailed](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) guide. It actually explains that you have to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to activate the function and also I had to change the line of code a bit.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone who wants to do the same thing like I did.

```
=INDEX(IB_RAW!I2:I301,MATCH(1,(IB_RAW!B2:B301=IB!P10)*(IB_RAW!D2:D301=IB!A9)*(IB_RAW!C2:C301=IB!Q9)*(IB_RAW!L2:L301=IB!P7),0))
```